Is security of Manuel Blum's Mental Hash function dependent on Security Through Obscurity for it's effectiveness?
I have been practicing using Manuel Blum's Mental Hash Function for personal use, described in the link below:
Mental Cryptography and Good Passwords
However, Rob Shearer has shown that the function itself is insecure as a hash with his blog post:
The "Blum Mental Hash" Is A Lousy Idea
For the use case of creating and using passwords without having to use a password manager on your computer or pen and paper to calculate the hash or any other physical artifacts other than what you can calculate in your head, is this "security through obscurity" provided that the plaintext, ciphertext, and keys are kept secret?

Shearer's analysis is sound, and precisely summarizes what's wrong. The key itself can be recovered using samples of ciphertext - which is exactly the opposite of what you want from cryptography.

I agree with Shearer's analysis, except for one point that his crack is based, "Upon further analysis, you can exploit the information leaked to reconstruct an entire key from just a few dozen encoded characters!"  My issue is that you're not supposed to leak your the ciphertext (i.e. your password).

@its.just.me Of course you're not supposed to ... but much of the point of cryptography is to be robustly resistant to attack if it happens anyway. There's not much use for cryptography that expects the ciphertext (the result of encryption) to remain secret.
